# running tkinter python code straight from book(runtime error)

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, tkinter, runtime

I'm currently learning python using a book called 'Programming Python', its a pretty good book thats give lots of code examples to make it easier to understand. I'm on the chapter that discusses tkinter but I'm finding that alot of the examples don't work when I put them in exactly the same as the book does(some do work, which is strange). I know the book works in python 3 and my python version is the same, anyone have any ideas? Heres the code.

```
__author__ = 'MgenGlder'
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class MyGui(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        button = Button(self, test = 'press', command = self.reply)
        button.pack()
    def reply(self):
        showinfo(title = 'popup', message = 'Button pressed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MyGui()
    window.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

The error I get is:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/MgenGlder/PycharmProjects/Programming Python/tkinter102.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MgenGlder/PycharmProjects/Programming Python/tkinter102.py", line 14, in <module>
    window = MyGui()
  File "C:/Users/MgenGlder/PycharmProjects/Programming Python/tkinter102.py", line 8, in __init__
    button = Button(self, test = 'press', command = self.reply)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2192, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2122, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-test"
```

Comment: In `button=Button(...`  it should be `text='press'` not `test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is (albeit in a slightly cryptic way):

```
unknown option "-test"
```

The problem is this line of code:

```
button = Button(self, test = 'press', command = self.reply)
```

`test = ...` should be `text = ...`.

Comment: Ahh yeah, thanks I did alittle research an realised the error in my ways. Thanks. If I may ask you another question(since im used to Java) why do you say "text = 'press' for the argument instead of just 'press'?

Comment: @MgenGlder: because these options can be supplied in any order. if you just say `press`, it may not be applied to the option you think it does. And even if you do get the order of arguments right, explicitly specifying the option name makes your code easier to understand.

Comment: @MgenGlder  Arguments can be matched to parameter names by position in the sequence of arguments, by name, or both, depending on how the function is defined.  The `Button.__init__` constructor only accepts 'master' and 'cnf' by position (where cnf is a dictionary mapping option names to argument objects).  Passing individual options must be done with `name=value`.  I believe all widget constructors are like this.

Comment: @MgenGlder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter